# Memory management for fetching a list of drive letters on Windows

Tags: c++, strings, memory-management, winapi

I'm using the WinAPI [`GetLogicalDriveStrings()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) function that requires a `LPWSTR` and am wondering if there is a safer way to do this to ensure there is no memory leak.

Currently I construct an initial pointer to a buffer `buf` using:

```
auto buf = GetLogicalDriveStrings(0, nullptr);
```

Then I create the LPWSTR to be used in lieu of the null pointer in my actual call using:

```
auto driveStrings = static_cast<LPWSTR>(malloc((buf + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)));
```

Next I create a pointer to `driveStrings` to free it later. After checking if `driveStrings` is a null pointer or if the buffer (`buf`) is `NULL` (in case memory couldn't be allocated), I call `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` using `driveStrings`.

After I get the result I manually `free()` the LPWSTR using the pointer I made after allocating it.

How can I use a smart pointer for LPWSTR instead so I don't have to use `malloc()` and `free()`, but so that it will still work with the [`GetLogicalDriveStrings()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) function?

**Mininum working example:**

```
auto buf = GetLogicalDriveStrings(0, nullptr);

auto driveStrings = static_cast<LPWSTR>(malloc((buf + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)));
auto pDriveStrings = driveStrings;

if (driveStrings == nullptr || buf == NULL)
{
    std::stringstream msg;
    msg << "Can't allocate memory for drive list: ";
    msg << GetLastError();
    throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
}

// get drive strings
if (GetLogicalDriveStrings(buf, driveStrings) == NULL)
{
    std::stringstream msg;
    msg << "GetLogicalDriveStrings error: ";
    msg << GetLastError();
    throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
}

// iterate over results
while (*driveStrings)
{
    // GetDriveType() requires a LPCWSTR
    if (GetDriveType(driveStrings) == DRIVE_FIXED || GetDriveType(driveStrings) == DRIVE_REMOVABLE)
    {
        std::wcout << driveStrings << std::endl;
    }
    driveStrings += lstrlen(driveStrings) + 1;
}

free(pDriveStrings);
```

If I use a `std::wstring`, I can't figure out how to iterate over each string in the `driveStrings` buffer. If I use a `std::vector<WCHAR>`, I can't figure out how to cast each element to an LPCWSTR for `GetDriveType()`.

This works fine as is, but is there a better/safer way to do this? I'm open to any and all improvements.

<sub>[Cross-posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42585906/868044), but it has close votes because it is a better fit here.</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, and thank you for declaring your cross-post. For the record, I don't believe that your question was off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is leaking memory. If you throw an exception, `free` no longer gets called. Using a `std::vector` makes sure the memory is freed.

Iterating through the array returned is quite straight-forward, considering that each drive letter has a null-terminator and than the whole vector has an extra null-terminator (`requiredSize` = `writtenChars + 1`)

```
auto requiredSize = GetLogicalDriveStringsW(0, nullptr);

std::vector<WCHAR> buffer(requiredSize + 1);
auto writtenChars = GetLogicalDriveStringsW(requiredSize, buffer.data());

if (writtenChars > requiredSize)
{
    //MSDN: If the buffer is not large enough, the return value is greater than nBufferLength.
}

if (writtenChars == 0)
{
    //handle error
}

const WCHAR* currentString = buffer.data();

while (*currentString != 0)
{
    std::wcout << currentString << L'\n';
    //pass currentString to other methods
    currentString += wcslen(currentString) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Please note that GetDriveType requires an LPCWSTR, not just a string. Would just passing its reference work for that?

Comment: Won't I then need to free `*currentString`? Would a smart pointer be be better here?

Comment: No, you wouldn't. `currentString` doesn't own the memory it's pointing to, the `std::vector` does is is responsible for freeing it.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense.